# Limited recreation of a button through a forloop

Tags: java, android

So I'm building this app where each time the floatActionButton is clicked, a button is created. That aspect of the app works fine. But my problem is that the buttons are being created on top of one another and are constantly created. I need to create only 4 buttons click after click, one below another.

This is my for-loop. I appreciate any help.

```
addingSemester.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++){
                    Button semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
                    semesterButton.setId(i);
                    semesterButton.setText("Semester " + i);
                    semesterButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
                    semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
                    i++;
                }
            }
        });
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity">

    <!--<LinearLayout-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:orientation="horizontal"-->
        <!--android:padding="6dp"-->
        <!--&gt;-->
        <!--<Button-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="Semester 1"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="4"-->
            <!--android:textColor="#FFFFFF"-->
            <!--android:background="#3F51B5"-->
            <!--/>-->
        <!--<TextView-->
            <!--android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
            <!--android:text="DELETE"-->
            <!--android:layout_weight="0.6"-->
            <!--android:clickable="true"-->
            <!--android:textAlignment="center"-->
            <!--/>-->

    <!--</LinearLayout>-->


        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addActionButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
            app:borderWidth="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are incrementing i both in the door process and explicitly in your loop. Not your problem, but will want to change that. If you have them in a RelativeLayout you will want to explicitly state where the new button lies in relation to the other. If it's linear it should be handled.

Comment: But when I switch to a linearlayout, my floatactionbutton goes to the top-left corner.

Comment: Show your xml code please.

Comment: Its up there...

Comment: Then use a relative layout, but you will need to explicitly set where the new views are being placed or they will just stack on top of one another. And my first comment should say in the for process, not door process :)

Comment: Hi.  I got it working with a LinearLayout.  My question now is that I want to set an onLongClickListener where when each dynamically generated button is long pressed, I want it to red and change the text to DELETE.  My problem is that I can't get the button's ID.  I tried using getId() and storing it in an int but it didn't work.  Basically I wanted to pop up an alert dialog.